# Retrieve value from map using keypath

Tags: terraform

Let's say I have an map and a keypath to a property nested deeply within:

```
locals {
    data = {
        a = {
            b = {
                c = "Hello World"
            }
        }
    }

    keypath = "a.b.c"
}
```

How can I get the value at the indicated keypath? The keypath can have any number of levels.

```
output "value" {
    value = local.data[???]    # Should return "Hello World"
}
```

Comment: You can't. Such thing is not supported in TF.

Comment: You need the equivalent of a `dig` function, which does not exist yet in Terraform.

Comment: I wanted to prove you wrong by splitting the `keypath` to a list and iterate the `data` with a recursive module, but unfortunately that leads to a cycle error: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/27248